# Is there a way to refer to the last created item (watch, break, disp) in GDB?

Tags: gdb

Is there a way that I can script the initialization file for GDB so that instead of:

```
break file.c:1234
commands 1
# ... fancy commands
end
```

... **if** I could write something like:

```
break file.c:1234 $line1234
commands  $line1234
# ... fancy commands
end
```

... i.e. remember what number was assigned to a break point, watch point etc - I would be able to continue using that last created item/entity. The question also applies to `disp`, `watch` and others.

This only becomes relevant when you have many many breakpoints, but then it will be very useful. I wasn't able to dig anything up from the documentation.

It would also be useful if there was just one magic variable that I could use to refer to the last created item of each type respectively, e.g. `$lastbp`, `$lastwp`, `$lastdisp` ...

---

I figured perhaps a better example is the one at hand:

```
break file.c:1234 $line1234
commands  $line1234
# ... fancy commands
end
ignore $line1234 42
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recent GDB versions (7.3) [expose breakpoints to Python scripting.](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Breakpoints-In-Python.html)

You can write a Python script to set them up, set conditions and commands on them, etc. etc.

Comment: Hmm, thanks. Unfortunately that would require me to make a custom build of GDB on the systems I'm working with. Still, once it becomes available I will know.